# Calculus - relation between integrals and functions (counterexample)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> If $g(x)\leq f(x)$ for every $x$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_x^{x+1}(f(t)-g(t)) dt =0 $ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$.

I am pretty sure the claim is false, but can't find a proper counterexample. I guess it has somehting to do with the fact that the integration is in the region $(x,x+1)$ rather than in an arbitrary interval, but do not know how to proceed.

Will be happy to receive your help.

Thank you!

Comment: What if $g(x)=0$, and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb Z$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to : if $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty }\int_x^{x+1}f(t)\,\mathrm d t=0,$$
then $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0,$$ which is indeed false. Take for example $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{(n,n+\frac{1}{n^2})}(x).$$ Even if you want $f$ being continuous it's wrong.

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you both!